# Need help traversing a tree; Huffman Coding

Tags: c++

I have created a Huffman Tree and It appears to be correct, however I am weak when it comes to traversing data structures. I drew out the Tree on paper based on the information contained in my root tree and it appears to be well, however My code is faulty and I do not know hot to fix it.

The first 0 is persisting and, every time i take right, it seems to append a 0 after.

```
example:
L: 01
H: 1111

but my traversal gives me:
L: 001
H: 01010101
```

code Snippets

```
struct node
{
int symbol;
int frequency;
node* left;
node* right;
};

void Huffman::generateCode(node *tree, std::string code)
{
    if(tree->left == NULL && tree->right == NULL)
    {
        //std::cout << "Leaf Found: " << tree->symbol << "\t" << code << std::endl;
        mapCode.insert(std::pair<int, std::string>(tree->symbol,code));
    }
    if(tree->left != NULL)
    {
        code.append("0");
        generateCode(tree->left, code);
    }
    if(tree->right != NULL)
    {
        code.append("1");
        generateCode(tree->right, code);
    }
}
```

UPDATE SOLVED: i figure out that the code.append(); function was messing it up. i changed it too code + "0";

```
void Huffman::generateCode(node *tree, std::string code)
{
    if(tree->left == NULL && tree->right == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Leaf Found: " << tree->symbol << "\t" << code << std::endl;
        mapCode.insert(std::pair<int, std::string>(tree->symbol,code));
    }
    if(tree->left != NULL)
    {
        generateCode(tree->left, code + "0");
    }
    if(tree->right != NULL)
    {
        generateCode(tree->right, code + "1");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your "solved" version works flawless on my java code. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed the `else`s:

```
void Huffman::generateCode(node *tree, std::string code)
{
    if(tree->left == NULL && tree->right == NULL)
    {
        //std::cout << "Leaf Found: " << tree->symbol << "\t" << code << std::endl;
        mapCode.insert(std::pair<int, std::string>(tree->symbol,code));
    }
    else if(tree->left != NULL)
    {
        code.append("0");
        generateCode(tree->left, code);
    }
    else if(tree->right != NULL)
    {
        code.append("1");
        generateCode(tree->right, code);
    }
}
```

Comment: aside from that I should point out that while I'm familiar with huffman coding, I really don't understand what you're doing here.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but by doing so will only return 1 value, i am building an map of coded values based off a tree

Comment: then how do you plan to choose left or right? Also you seem to be missing some recursion.

Comment: It is missing recursion only if you apply the "else if"... All 'if's are needed and his "solved" version works just good.